# How to install plugins

Tags: go, plugins

TL;DR: Where do `.so` files end up when you install plugins with `go install -buildmode=plugin`?

I have a project that uses plugins. The layout is something like this:

```
myproject/
├── main.go
└── modules
    ├── bar
    │   └── main.go
    └── foo
        └── main.go
```

When I run `go install` the binary gets installed OK.
But I would also like to run `go install` for each of my modules and have them available to the main binary everywhere on the system.
If I run `go install -buildmode=plugin` from inside a module folder (say, `modules/foo`) the command runs to completion but I can't find the resulting file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a normal package ends up in:

```
GOPATH/pkg/<goos>_<goarch>_dynlink/path/to/parent/folder/packagename.a
```

Installing `main` packages end up in:

```
GOPATH/bin/foldername
```

(where `foldername` is the parent folder of the `main` package you install, it'll get an `.exe` extension on windows).

When you "go install" a plugin (using `-buildmode=plugin`), that ends up in

```
GOPATH/pkg/<goos>_<goarch>_dynlink/path/to/parent/folder/foldername.a
```